# How can I disable collisions for all sibling game objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a spawner which spawns balloons every second. I want to stop these balloons from colliding with other balloons. I can see how you can loop through child objects from a parent, but I don't know how to loop through other child objects that share the same parent. All balloons are spawned in the same parent.

Currently I have this but it obviously doesn't work. I tried `transform.parent.transform` too but this didn't work either. It only spawns one balloon and the script breaks for "object not set to an instance of an object" on the same line.

```
var NewBalloon = Instantiate(balloons[0], transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(-90, 0, 0)));
NewBalloon.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("Balloons").transform;

foreach(Transform child in transform.parent)
{
      Physics.IgnoreCollision(NewBalloon.GetComponent<Collider>(), child.GetComponent<Collider>());
}
```

Comment: spawn the balloons with a certain *tag* and then only agknowledge collisions for objects which *do not* have that tag

Comment: Well actually they only need to collide with one object which is the projectile used to burst them.

Comment: @Martin I've managed to achieve this with layers, not sure how you can do this with tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite the way I intended to do it, but I found that if you go to `"Edit" > "Project Settings" > "Physics"` (on version 5.5), I could disable the checkbox for balloons / balloons which stops them colliding with each other.

Edit: This seems to be the best way to do it. No need to add scripting for it, and it just works perfectly.

Comment: This is the smart way to do this anyway.

Comment: I found lots of tutorials explaining to loop through objects to do this. Not sure when they introduced the layers option but it's far far better!

Comment: The scripting method is required and is needed if you have many many objects. Let's say hundreds of objects in different layers. It would take time to do that from the Editor. With script, that's only one-time stuff and you are done!

Answer (score 2):

> but I don't know how to loop through other child objects that share
>   the same parent.

**You don't have to!**

This is really easy. Just create a layer and put the balloon prefab in the layer. Let's say Layer 9.

Now, run this in the `Awake` function to ignore collison between each balloon in that layer:

```
Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(9, 9, true);
```

If you want to recognize collison, run this:

```
Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(9, 9, false);
```

That's it.

Comment: Ah that's a neat way to do this programmically. Many thanks for your input!